# Importing file (without extension) contents into python script as object

Tags: python, import, module, token

I have a file titled "passc" (no .txt, no .py, no extension at all) that contains a single line of code (its a token) similar to:
       `aABBccDd01234`

Yes, there are no quotes or variable assignment in this file

I am trying to import this value into a python script and assign it to a variable (I think it should look something like this):

```
import passc

code = passc
```

I have tried variations of the following:

```
from passc import *
code = passc[0]
```

And I understand I'm importing a module not a direct object so it shouldn't have a subscriptable element, but I thought I might as well try it.

Without defining the value in "passc" file I can't figure out how to access the value.

Looking for suggestions on how to access this value without altering the "passc" file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not complicate yourself using `import passc` or `from passc import *` of this way only we can import files with .py extension.

The fast solution to fix this problem is doing something like this:

```
# read file
my_file=open("passc","r")
# save code in a var
code = my_file.read()

print(code)
# aABBccDd01234
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I wanted. Just a heads up to other users that I had to add a full path name to "passc" even though the the two files are in the same folder. Thanks @Freddy Daniel